# How to get every kw called with pytest in pytest_reports

Tags: python, pytest, jira-xray

I have to custom @pytest.mark decorator to build xray reports (and push it ...)
With the new parametrized tests xray feature, and associated steps, I would like to get every kw called during iteration (marked as a step)
hooks documentation is not so clean to me and i don't find how to do this...
does anyone have an idea ?

pytest : 6.2.4

Edit :

test example

```
import pytest

class Test(object):
    @pytest.mark.xray(test_key='DEMO-1')
    @pytest.mark.parametrize('param1, param2', [(2, 2), (3, 4), (5, 5), (5, 5), (6, "a"), ("aa", "aa")])
    def test_pytest_parametrized_feature_d(self, param1, param2):
        self.kw_one(param1, param2)
        self.kw_three(param1, param2)
        assert param1 == param2

    def kw_one(self, param1, param2):
        self.kw_two(param1, param2)

    def kw_two(self, param1, param2):
        print(param1)
        print(param2)

    def kw_three(self, param1, param2):
        assert param1 == param2
```

Expected result :
steps : kw_one : PASSED
kw_two : PASSED
kw_three : FAILED

I expect informations in pytest hooks, like : def pytest_terminal_summary(terminalreporter, exitstatus, config):

Comment: Can you please share a simple example of the code you have? Btw, what do you mean exactly with "I would like to get every kw called"?

Comment: Sure ! 
I have added example in original post

Comment: thanks. what would be relation, if any, between the "kw_*" methods  and the Test in Xray? would they relate to the manual steps? If so, then I see there a challenge of how to map kw_something to some *specific* step in Xray, as those steps don't have ids.. they just have an implicit index

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
not really ... the aim of the feature is to add steps dynamically (even if not defined manually). Xray allow this since last release, with "pytest with steps" test cases.

Comment: I'd love to pair with you to explore this further. I did some experiments with pytest but I also don't know enough yet about these more advanced use cases

Comment: thanks @Sérgio . See you in the further then !